# why my python scraping script is not working for different urls?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i wrote a scraping script using python for 2 different urls

http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA

http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=concrete+contractors&locationClue=nsw+australia&lat=&lon=&selectedViewMode=list

for 1st url i wrote following script

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url = requests.get("http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA") 


url.content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content) 
print (soup.prettify()) 


g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})
for item in g_data:
print (item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text)
```

it printed all the text in the names of business. But when i was use the same structured but different script for 2nd url it get the url content but not as enitre content from the page as the 1st url did.

2nd url script

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url = requests.get("http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=concrete+contractors&locationClue=nsw+australia&lat=&lon=&selectedViewMode=list") 


url.content 
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content) 
print (soup.prettify()) 


g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "body left"})
for item in g_data:
print (item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "listing-name"})[0].text)
```

my question is why it is not working as the first script and not giving the names of business

Answer (score 0):

You should see the content of `soup.prettify()` first. The website of `www.yellowpages.com.au` may be protected by firewall, which ensure real humans are accessing their information.
If the first step is okay, then you can fetch the content of website and debug the rest code. Maybe `find_all`'s attr argument is wrong, refs [Searching by CSS class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attrs)

Comment: soup.prettify() is working but it is not extract enitre html content of the page source as the 1st url done. how could i get html content as 1st page?

Comment: The website detected unusual traffic activity when you get the content of 2nd url. If you run your script, then you open 2nd url by browser, which will be redirect to HCI verification page, you must bypass the verification. You can search bypass reCaptcha in google.